# Object tracking without openCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to build up an algorithm to detect some objects and track them over time. My input data is a tif multi-stack file, which I read as a `np` array. I apply a U-Net model to create a binary mask and then identify the coordinates of single objects using `scipy`.

Up to here everything kind of works but I just cannot get my head around the tracking. I have a dictionary where keys are the frame numbers and values are lists of tuples. Each tuple contain the coordinates of each object.

Now I have to link the objects together, which on paper seems pretty simple. I was hoping there was a function or a package to do so (ideally something similar to `trackMate` or M2track on `ImageJ`), but I cannot find anything like that. I am considering writing my own nearest neighbor tool but I'd like to know whether there is a less painful way (and also, I would like to consider also more advanced metrics).

The other option I considered is using `cv2`, but this would require converting the data in a format `cv2` likes, which will significantly slow down the code. In addition, I would like to keep the data as close as possible to the original input, so no `cv2` for me.

Comment: OpenCV is happy with Numpy arrays & if you are using SciPy then I guess you are already working with Numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using trackpy.
http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.5.0/
trackpy properly reads multistack tiff files (OpenCv can't).